Can I feed seafood to my SeaMonkeys (also known as Brine Shrimp or Artemia)?
I keep a Nassarius snail with SeaMonkeys (also known as Artemia or Brine Shrimp) and I was hoping to condense their feeding schedule into one. My assumption is that the SeaMonkeys will eat any leftover's from the Nassarius but I wasn't certain.
Can SeaMonkeys eat frozen fish food / meat (silversides, krill, etc.)? Do they need any other source of nutrients?
Should I only purchase omnivore cubes (such as those with Spirlina) or are SeaMonkeys healthy living on carnivorous packs?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.
